# extract a string from

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net

I have the following string

```
29  This is a Page1  6754001  1,2,3,4
6755  This is a Page2 56-0 7654564 
 This is a Page3  67543-986xx 8 12
 This is (Page5)& Container 876-0 6 8xp
```

From the above, I need to extract the below text

```
This is a Page1 
 This is a Page2
 This is a Page3
 This is (Page5)& Container
```

There is always a space between the first number and the text so there is  a space between 2129 and This is  page1. Sometimes the first number is
 omitted like 2129 is gone. There is always a space between the text and the next number so there is a space between This is a Page1 and 6754001 and
 sometimes there can be two spaces.
I just need to extract these lines
These line always start after  space so it can be

```
29 This is page1
```

and they are always succeeded by a space, sometimes one space and sometimes two spaces.

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^\d*.*?\s+|(?<=\s)\d{2,}.*(?=\s|$)
```

Try this.This will work with your latest requriement.See demo

http://regex101.com/r/gG5fF6/4

Comment: @Anjali5 try this regex for the latest requirement of yours which you had put in another question

Comment: I tried this   Dim rgx As Regex = New Regex("^\d*.*?\s+|(?<=\s)\d{2,}.*(?=\s|$)")
        For Each m As Match In rgx.Matches(parse)
            Nomen = m.Groups(1).Value
        Next its just giving me the first value

Comment: @Anjali5 You have to replace by blank.dont match

Comment: replace by blank? should I replace the blank with something?

Comment: @Anjali5 Regex.Replace(str, @"(?m)^\d*.*?\s+|(?<=\s)\d{2,}.*(?=\s|$)", "");

Answer (score 3):

You could try the below regex to get the text which is preceded by an optional number at the start and followed by one or more spaces and a digit.

**Regex:**

```
^(?:\d+)?\s*(.*?)\s+\d.*
```

**Replacement string:**

```
$1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bP1oN6/1)

Through string replacement,

**Code**:

```
string str = @"29  This is a Page1  6754001  1,2,3,4
6755  This is a Page2 56-0 7654564 
 This is a Page3  67543-986xx 8 12
 This is (Page5)& Container 876-0 6 8xp";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"(?m)^(?:\d+)?\s*(.*?)\s+\d.*", "$1");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

```
This is a Page1
This is a Page2
This is a Page3
This is (Page5)& Container
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/aQr3xk)

**OR**

Through `Matches` method.

```
string str = @"29  This is a Page1  6754001  1,2,3,4
6755  This is a Page2 56-0 7654564 
 This is a Page3  67543-986xx 8 12
 This is (Page5)& Container 876-0 6 8xp";
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?m)^(?:\d+)?\s*(.*?)\s+\d.*");
foreach (Match m in rgx.Matches(str))
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/8gY4DP)